# d3 line chart using a sorted data set

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm making a pretty simple line chart, but I can't quite wrap my head around it. The problem is with my line() function.

```
// Define the line
var valueline = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.Wk); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.Rk); });

// Get the data
d3.csv("apdata.csv", function(error, data) {
    data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.Rk = +(d.Rk);
        d.Wk = +(d.Wk);
    });
```

this works fine, but my data isn't sorted the way I want. So I used d3.nest() to sort my data like this:

```
    var sortedData = d3.nest()
  .key(function(d){return d.School; })
  .entries(data);
```

Now my data looks good when I dump it in the console, but how do I draw my line based on my sorted data and not the original data. I tried changing my line function to this?

```
 var valueline = d3.svg.line()
 .x(function(d) { return x(sortedData.Arizona.Wk); })
 .y(function(d) { return y(sortedData.Arizona.Rk); });
```

But it keeps telling me Arizona is undefined.

My sorted data looks like this

```
[{"Arizona":[{Conf: "Pac-12"},{RK:10},{Wk:1}]}] .... etc
```

I'm clearly very confused. Any help would be much appreciated. First-time poster, so sorry if I broke some rules.

**Edit**
Hey guys, thanks for the help. I think I'm in a bit over my head. I figured out how to access my sortedData object, but now I need to figure out how to draw lines with it.

```
sortedData.forEach(function(d){
  ranks = +(d.values[0].Rk);
  weeks = +(d.values[0].Wk);
});

var valueline = d3.svg.line()
.x(function(d) { return x(ranks);})
.y(function(d) { return y(weeks); });
```

I'm not getting any errors, but I'm not getting any graphs either. I appreciate you all trying to help me out. I just don't think I really understand how the d3.svg.line() function works. Maybe what I really need is a good tutorial on D3 line graphs. Especially multi line graphs?

Here's the original csv. I feel like this project shouldn't be that hard.

http://pastebin.com/YY5YW320

Comment: Could you show what the data looked like before you sorted it? Just trying to get a sense of what the object structure should look like for it to work

Comment: yep! any help would be much appreciated. http://pastebin.com/YY5YW320

Answer (score 0):

The resulting data structure created by d3.nest() creates new records where the *key* field is the School grouping with a *values* field that contains an array of the rows associated with each school.

d3noob created a helpful example of how to create a multi-line chart (http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/d8be922a10cb0b148cd5). Run the snippet below to view an example how how you could plug your data into this code sample.

```js
// Set the dimensions of the canvas / graph
var margin = {top: 30, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
    width = 450 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 200 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// Set the ranges
var x = d3.scale.linear().range([0, width]);
var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);

// Define the axes
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x)
    .orient("bottom").ticks(5);

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y)
    .orient("left").ticks(5);

// Define the line
var valueline = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.Wk); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.Rk); });
    
// Adds the svg canvas
var svg = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
        .attr("transform", 
              "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// Get the data
var data = [
{Wk:1,Rk:10,School:"Arizona"},
{Wk:2,Rk:10,School:"Arizona"},
{Wk:3,Rk:8,School:"Arizona"},
{Wk:4,Rk:16,School:"Arizona"},
{Wk:5,Rk:20,School:"Arizona"},
{Wk:1,Rk:1,School:"Duke"},
{Wk:2,Rk:1,School:"Duke"},
{Wk:3,Rk:6,School:"Duke"},
{Wk:4,Rk:5,School:"Duke"},
{Wk:5,Rk:5,School:"Duke"}];

data.forEach(function(d) {
  d.Rk = +(d.Rk);
    d.Wk = +(d.Wk);
});

// Scale the range of the data
x.domain([d3.min(data, function(d) {return d.Wk; }), d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.Wk; })]);
y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.Rk; })]); 

// Nest the entries by symbol
var sortedData = d3.nest()
    .key(function(d) {return d.School;})
    .entries(data);

// Loop through each symbol / key
sortedData.forEach(function(d) {
  svg.append("path")
      .attr("class", "line")
      .attr("d", valueline(d.values));
});

// Add the X Axis
svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis);

// Add the Y Axis
svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(yAxis);
```

```css
body { font: 12px Arial;}

path { 
    stroke: steelblue;
    stroke-width: 2;
    fill: none;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
    fill: none;
    stroke: grey;
    stroke-width: 1;
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This is wrong.. Based on what OP said his new data is an array of objects. `sortedData.Arizona` doesn't work because sortedData doesn't have an Arizona property. `sortedData[0].Arizona[0].Conf` works because its properly drilling down into his new data structure. OP should probably be sorting his data with a different approach from `.nest()`

Comment: Thanks everybody. here's the original csv http://pastebin.com/YY5YW320

maybe I'm not nesting the data properly. I just wanted to sort the csv by School, so it would be easier to draw one line for each school.